# How to compute a matrix from a given basis?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let V be the $C$-vector space with basis $B$ := $(1,\cos(x),\sin(x))$.

> Define the linear operator $$J:V→V \text{ by } (J[f])(x):=\int _0^{\pi }\:f\left(x-t\right)dt$$ for all $f∈V$.

How would one come up with the matrix J with respect to this basis?

Comment: Find the images of the basis elements under $J$, express them in the same basis, and write down the answers as columns. So $J(1)$ is the first column, $J(\sin x)$ is the second column, and $J(\cos x)$ is the third column.